# How to project feature class located into 3 UTM Zones?

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, web-mapping, arcgis-silverlight-api, saudi-arabia

i have created a silverlight API web map application,for Saudi Arabia country, i have created a 3 search button, once search for "X,y", the problem with me is to how to define a probability projection for this country, KSA located into 3 UTM Zones, i i have already added UTM Zone 38 only for all feature classes but when i entered number for another area located into 37 zone the search result not correct it showing me into zone 38 only.

[image: some_text]

[image: some_text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear about your question, but why don't you reproject the dataset into WGS84? That way your points in the three UTM zones will have similar XY values. It also should work well since you're working with a web map.